# CollectionViewCell Push Segue In Storyboard Not Working (other push segue from same VC does)

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

*Disclaimer: I know this is really messy, and I will refactor this into a viewcontainer later on, but I am curious about what the exact problem is here*

I have a viewcontroller with a tableview and a collectionview. I have set up the cell in the tableview to push a detailsviewcontroller upon selection. That works, but when I add a collectionview on the same viewcontroller, it does not work.

However, if I add the function at didSelectItemAtIndexPath, the function does get triggered, so I am pretty sure it is not a view issue but a storyboard one.

[image]